# Writing a SUMIFS formula in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

Worksheet:

[image: Worksheet picture]

Please see the attached picture for most cell locations.

I am creating a work tracker to capture metrics for hours and values for various reports and logs for individuals.

I have been attempting to figure out how to create the needed formula. If there is potentially an easier way, I am all ears.

Example of how I want it the formula (seen below) to behave:

`M34:M38` all have `123test123`

`J34` is filled with `“Name1”`

`F34:F38` all contain different values to sum

The summed values are then returned to the cell that has the formula that has `“Name1”` in `P3("*"&P3&"*")`

`M39:M48` all have `456test456`

`J39` is filled with `“Name2”`

`F39:F48` all contain different values to sum

The summed values are then returned to the cell that has the formula that has `“Name2”` in `P4("*"&P4&"*")`

This process will continue until the end of the range.

To sum it up, the data in `M` may be in any given range within the column.
Sum the `F` row that matches (see example).
Return that value to the cell(`W3`) with the formula that matches the criteria from `P3`.

In an attempt to explain better.

Column `M` will have multiple different JCNs input throughout the month, with a varying quantity of assets. This will change the number of cells in column `M`; all will have the same JCN.

The hours, job type, crew chief, crew members and date are going to be unique for the JCN, I would compare it to Keys in a database tying that data to that individual JCN.

Every job is a different JCN that is a unique ID formatted as `123ABC12-3`.
I wish to match the rows with the identical JCNs in `M` to the values in `F`; sum those values, return to the cells with the formulas in `W3`(Crew Chief)/`X3`(Crew Member) matching the wildcard indicator from `P3` such as `"*"&P3&"*"`.

`F34:F38` has a dollar value.
`M34:M38` will have identical JCN's- Note:The number of cells with the same JCN can and will change based on the quantity of items for the job.

Using the JCN in `M34:M38`
SUM the values from `F34:F38` and send it to 'W'row/'X'row with the wildcard identifier for the names in both Crew Chief`J34` and Crew Member `O34`.
[Table_Data_is_being_fed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMMt7.png)
This should will allow me to capture all the data in the for the member in the sheet.

If this would be better off in something like Access. I am willing to attempt that route, but this was already a half finished spreadsheet when I took over managing my section.

```
=SUMIFS($F$34:$F$310, $M$34:$M$310, "="&M34, $J$34:$J$310, "=""*"&P3&"*")
```

The formula above is as far as I have gotten.

The second formula(`X3`) will behave similarly to the first one. But if the same name is in both `J` and `O`, the data in `O` will be ignored and not calculate.

I tried multiple formulas with no luck.

In `W3`:

```
=SUMIFS($G$34:$G$310,$J$34:$J$310,"*" & P3 &"*")=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($J$34:$J$310<>"")($O$34:$O$310<>"")($J$34:$J$310=$O$34:$O$310)($J$34:$J$310<>""&P3&"")($O$34:$O$310<>""&P3&"")($O$34:$O$310=""&P3&"*"),MATCH($J$34:$J$310,$J$34:$J$310,0)),IF($J$34:$J$310<>"",ROW($J$34:$J$310)-ROW($J$34)+1)),ROW($J$34:$J$310)-MIN(ROW($J$34:$J$310))+1))-COUNTBLANK($J$34:$J$310))
```

In `X3`:

```
=SUMIFS($F$34:$F$310,$O$34:$O$310,"="&$O$34,$J$34:$J$310,"<>"&$O$34,$O$34:$O$310,"*"&P3&"*",$J$34:$J$310,"<>"&"*"&P3&"*")
```

Comment: The attached screenshot doesn't match the textual description, does it?

Comment: you're correct. M34 has an the incorrect number in it. I forgot to change it to match M35(had an issue with a touchpad and had to click and drag to repopulate the number) for the screenshot. The colors in the screenshot represents the types of data that I would expect my users to input.

Comment: I was referring to "M34:M38 all have 123test123, M39:M48 all have 456test456". Anyway I wanted to let you know I was not able to understand the question the way it was presented.

Comment: That's correct. As shown in column N (JCN) we will have multiple JCNs throughout the month, with a varying degree of assets that are worked on.  To hopefully better explain my conundrum. Each job is a different JCN that is unique. Each JCN will have a crew chief and crew that completes the job.